# How symbian V3 get id3 info from a MP3 file

Tags: mp3, symbian, id3

I am writting a music player on Symbian v3. But I can’t find How can I get id3 info from a mp3 file.Is there any API to do this ? How can I use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ID3 data from an MP3 using the CMetaDataUtility API. It's not part of the public SDK, but you can download the SDK API Plug-in via this [Nokia Developer](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Audio_Metadata_Reader_API) page that also has example code.

This will work in S60 3rd edition, 5th edition, and Symbian^3.